# Ubuntu MATE - Shutting down wifi hardware to conserve energy RaspberryPi

Tags: command-line, networking, nmcli

I'm trying to shut down wifi HW (not only disconnecting) for the sake of keeping my battery as much as possible.

I'm using `nmcli` to connect/ disconnect wifi everytime  a message is needed to be sent.

Is there a way to turn off HW as well ?

As pasted below- it can be seen that WIFI is `disabled` but WIFI-HW is `enabled`.

Guy

```
guy@guy-desktop:~/Documents/github/Rpi$ nmcli radio all
WIFI-HW  WIFI      WWAN-HW  WWAN    
enabled  disabled  enabled  enabled
```

Answer (score 1):

The OS can not turn off WIFI-WH and, even if it could, it would not affect the battery.

```
nmcli radio all
```

reports the kernel's rfkill status for all radio devices.  As per rfkill's kernel [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rfkill.txt):

> The rfkill subsystem provides a generic interface for disabling any radio
>   transmitter in the system. When a transmitter is blocked, it shall not
>   radiate any power.

and

> The rfkill subsystem has a concept of "hard" and "soft" block, which
>   differ little in their meaning (block == transmitters off) but rather in
>   whether they can be changed or not